# Android List View Scrolling Items Randomize

Tags: android, list, listview, android-listview, view

my ListView works fine except when I scroll fast some of the items are duplicated and in random order. It's kind of hard to explain but here's the beginning of my getView method.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    View view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }else{
        view = convertView;
    }.......
```

In my MainActivity I call notifySetAdapterChanged(). Anyone know how to fix this?

Here is what the Logcat says each getView():

-Layouts #:1 and position is 0

- Layouts #:1 and position is 0
  Layouts #:2 and position is 1
  Layouts #:3 and position is 2
  Layouts #:4 and position is 3
  Layouts #:5 and position is 4
  Layouts #:6 and position is 5
  Layouts #:7 and position is 6
  Layouts #:8 and position is 7
  Layouts #:9 and position is 8
  //click one of the list items
  Layouts #:10 and position is 0
  Layouts #:11 and position is 1
  Layouts #:12 and position is 2
  Layouts #:13 and position is 3
  Layouts #:14 and position is 4
  Layouts #:14 and position is 5
  Layouts #:14 and position is 6
  Layouts #:14 and position is 7
  Layouts #:14 and position is 8
  Layouts #:14 and position is 0
  Layouts #:14 and position is 1
  Layouts #:14 and position is 2
  Layouts #:14 and position is 3
  Layouts #:14 and position is 4
  Layouts #:14 and position is 5
  Layouts #:14 and position is 6
  Layouts #:14 and position is 7

Comment: This is not a solution for your problem, but you should always inflate the new view inside the parent ViewGroup without adding it. In your case:

`view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, arg2, false);`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Already implemented it.